# How to extract filename from getData() in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

I am uploading the file on Firebase storage and want to keep the original name of file rather than giving it custom name by using timestamp

This is the code i have written:

This is the code i have written in onActivityResult which fetches the file url

```
 else if (requestCode == filepickcode)
        {
            fileuri = data.getData();
            sendfilemessage(fileuri);

        }
```

This is the file upload method:

```
private void sendfilemessage(Uri fileuri) {
    pb.showdia();

    final String timestamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    String filenameandpath = "ChatDocuments/" + "post" + timestamp;

    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(filenameandpath);
    ref.putFile(fileuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();

            while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
            String downloaduri = uriTask.getResult().toString();

            if (uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("sender", myUid);
                hashMap.put("receiver", hisUid);
                hashMap.put("message", downloaduri);
                hashMap.put("timestamp", timestamp);
                hashMap.put("type", "file");
                hashMap.put("read", "no");
                hashMap.put("downloaded", "no");

                databaseReference.child("Chats").child(myUid).child(hisUid).push().setValue(hashMap);
                databaseReference.child("Chats").child(hisUid).child(myUid).push().setValue(hashMap);

                pb.dismissdia();

            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

I wanna extract the name of the pdf file and send it in database and then extract it so i could show the name of the pdf file below the pdf imageview holder

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to get your file name

```
                   String filePath = null;

                    Log.d("", "URI = " + selectedMediaUri);
                    if (selectedMediaUri != null && "content".equals(selectedMediaUri.getScheme())) {
                        Cursor cursor = baseActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedMediaUri, new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        filePath = cursor.getString(0);
                        cursor.close();
                    } else {
                        filePath = selectedMediaUri.getPath();
                    }




File fname=new File(filePath);
String filename = fname.getName();
```

Comment: No. That delivers comlete path to the file. For file name only use column .DISPLAY_NAME instead.